# HCYoutubeParser not working

Tags: objective-c, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the HCYoutubeParser on my app, that fetches video info using:

```
http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=/*VIDEO ID*/
```

This only fetches videos that can be played in embed players, which isn't many videos. I wanted to fetch vevo videos, yet I can't figure out how to do it.
I have tried:

```
http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=/*VIDEO ID*/&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US
```

But it doesnt work. Is there any API I can connect to, or is there a work around for this?